# Friday night kiddush in shule - is this a bracha l'vatalla?

Tags: blessing, kiddush

For those shules that have the minhag to make Kiddush in shule on Friday night - why is this not a bracha l'vatalla?
Yes, I am aware that the Gemara mentions this was done in the shules in those days to benefit anyone staying in the shule. However, we don't have people staying in our shules these days. Yes, the sha"tz (or youngsters)drink the wine, but the text of the "full" Kiddush isn't said. It's not said b'makom seuda. Finally, whoever makes the Kiddush in shule still goes home and has to say it again.

Why isn't this a bracha l'vatalla?

(I'm also wondering if this minhag is only in chu"l. I can't recall the Friday night shule Kiddush being done in any of the shules I've been in while in E"Y.)

Comment: Why isn't the chazzan's repetition a bracha levatala?

Comment: "the text of the "full" Kiddush isn't said" Not sure what you mean by this

Comment: I meant that the shule Kiddush doesn't include ויכולו.

Comment: They just all said ויכלו two paragraphs prior

Comment: @Double AA There's quite an interruption in there (various paragraphs said by the sha"tz, Magen Avot said by the both the congregation and the shat"z, then a full Kaddish.) Even shules that don't say Kiddush say ויכלו. I don't think it was really included as part of the Kiddish.

Comment: The general rule is that in order to stop a practice that was enacted by a group of  sages requires another group of sages to abolish it

Comment: Also, the only reason why ויכולו is repeated before Kiddush is in order to be Motzi his wife and kids who were not in Shul

Comment: @elshpen doesn't matter. It's not a part of kiddush but just something everyone should say Friday night so we customarily say it adjacent to something else said every Friday night namely kiddush.